# AngularJS - Angular-Charts : nothing happens

Tags: javascript, angularjs, charts

Sorry, my question is probably very stupid, might seem obvious to you.

I would like to display a chart with my app using angular-charts. 
I have followed the instructions on : http://chinmaymk.github.io/angular-charts/, but I have a problem:

-if I write the dependency, I have an error `Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'angularCharts' is not available! You either missp...<omitted>...1)`

-if not, nothing happens.

Here is my code :

HTML

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>myApp</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
  <script src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/angular/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>

  <script type='text/javascript' href='lib\angular\angular-charts.min.js'></script>

</head>
<body>
<div ng-controller="plotGraph" ng-repeat="graph in graphs" class="test-container">
        <div ac-chart="chartType" ac-data="dataGraph" ac-config="config" id='graph'     class='graph'></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

App.js

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['angularCharts']);
function plotGraph($scope){
console.log("And here is the graph part");

//Graph
$scope.chartType = 'line'

$scope.config = {
    labels: false,
    title : "myTitle",
    tooltips: true,
    legend : {
        display:true,
        position:'myLegend'
    }
}

$scope.dataGraph = {
    series: ['Server1'], //I could put there the different server
    data : [{ //{} for each serie
        x : "myXAxis",
        y: [10,50,12,35,16,22],
        tooltip:"this is tooltip"
    }
    ]     
}

}
```

I just want to add that I have downloaded the zip, and just copy/paste the file `angular-charts.min.js` in the folder where I have all these other "type of files".
Maybe this is the problem.

Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

First include

```
<script type='text/javascript' href='lib\angular\angular-charts.min.js'></script>
```

then your app.js

Thans how your index file should look like:

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>myApp</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
  <script src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/angular/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' href='lib\angular\angular-charts.min.js'></script>
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>



</head>
<body>
<div ng-controller="plotGraph" ng-repeat="graph in graphs" class="test-container">
        <div ac-chart="chartType" ac-data="dataGraph" ac-config="config" id='graph'     class='graph'></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Always make sure, that your libaries are included first on the page, then your application logic :)

Comment: Great, I have no more error, thank you :)

For information, I also modified my line:

    <script src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script>

However, the function doesn't display anything on my webpage. Would you have any clue about this problem ?

Comment: I thinks that, there might be problem with "/" and "\", make sure you always have / in path files

Answer (score 0):

Chart.js is missing

Install chart.js using bower components..

you will get two folder.Angular-chart and chart folder. You have to refer chart.js file also